# Rigid Body does not tread well on the ground

Tags: 3d-view, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body, rigidbody, resolution

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have a problem about Rigid Body. It does not tread well on the ground.

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx